# System.Format exception when consuming Akka.Persistence configuration

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-cluster, akka.net-persistence, akka.fsharp

I am struggling to troubleshoot a *System.Format* exception that results from parsing my *Akka.Net* config file.

**I know that the exception stems from the persistence block of the configuration:**

```
persistence{
    journal {
      plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.sql-server"
        sql-server {
            # qualified type name of the SQL Server persistence journal actor
            class = "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"

            # dispatcher used to drive journal actor
            plugin-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"

            # connection string used for database access
            connection-string = "Data Source=MyMachineName\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

            # default SQL commands timeout
            connection-timeout = 30s

            # SQL server schema name to table corresponding with persistent journal
            schema-name = dbo

            # SQL server table corresponding with persistent journal
            table-name = EventJournal

            # should corresponding journal table be initialized automatically
            auto-initialize = off

            # timestamp provider used for generation of journal entries timestamps
            timestamp-provider = "Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Journal.DefaultTimestampProvider, Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common"

            # metadata table
            metadata-table-name = Metadata
        }
    }

    snapshot-store {
        sql-server {

            # qualified type name of the SQL Server persistence journal actor
            class = "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotStore, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"

            # dispatcher used to drive journal actor
            plugin-dispatcher = ""akka.actor.default-dispatcher""

            # connection string used for database access
            connection-string = "Data Source=MyMachineName\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

            # default SQL commands timeout
            connection-timeout = 30s

            # SQL server schema name to table corresponding with persistent journal
            schema-name = dbo

            # SQL server table corresponding with persistent journal
            table-name = SnapshotStore

            # should corresponding journal table be initialized automatically
            auto-initialize = off
        }
    }
}
```

**The output reflecting the exception is the following:**

```
Binding session to 'C:\Users\Snimrod\Desktop\Akkling-master\examples\../src/Akkling.Cluster.Sharding/bin/Debug/Akka.dll'...
System.FormatException: Unknown escape code: S
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.HoconTokenizer.PullEscapeSequence()
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.HoconTokenizer.PullQuotedText()
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.HoconTokenizer.PullValue()
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.Parser.ParseValue(HoconValue owner, String currentPath)
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.Parser.ParseKeyContent(HoconValue value, String currentPath)
>    at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.Parser.ParseObject(HoconValue owner, Boolean root, String currentPath)
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.Parser.ParseKeyContent(HoconValue value, String currentPath)
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.Parser.ParseObject(HoconValue owner, Boolean root, String currentPath)
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.Parser.ParseKeyContent(HoconValue value, String currentPath)
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.Parser.ParseObject(HoconValue owner, Boolean root, String currentPath)
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.Parser.ParseKeyContent(HoconValue value, String currentPath)
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.Parser.ParseObject(HoconValue owner, Boolean root, String currentPath)
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.Parser.ParseKeyContent(HoconValue value, String currentPath)
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.Parser.ParseObject(HoconValue owner, Boolean root, String currentPath)
   at Akka.Configuration.Hocon.Parser.ParseText(String text, Func`2 includeCallback)
   at Akka.Configuration.ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(String hocon)
   at Akkling.Configuration.parse(String arg00) in C:\Users\Snimrod\Desktop\Akkling-master\src\Akkling\Spawning.fs:line 30
   at FSI_0003.configWithPort[a](a port) in C:\Users\Snimrod\Desktop\Akkling-master\examples\cluster-sharding.fsx:line 148
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0003>.$FSI_0003.main@() in C:\Users\Snimrod\Desktop\Akkling-master\examples\cluster-sharding.fsx:line 154
Stopped due to error
```

**My entire configuration is the following:**

```
let configWithPort port =
    let config = Configuration.parse ("""
        akka {
            actor {
              provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
              serializers {
                hyperion = "Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializer, Akka.Serialization.Hyperion"
              }
              serialization-bindings {
                "System.Object" = hyperion
              }
            }
          remote {
            helios.tcp {
              public-hostname = "localhost"
              hostname = "localhost"
              port = """ + port.ToString() + """
            }
          }
          cluster {
            auto-down-unreachable-after = 5s
            seed-nodes = [ "akka.tcp://cluster-system@localhost:2551/" ]
          }

          # persistence {
          #  journal.plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.inmem"
          #  snapshot-store.plugin = "akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local"
          # }

          persistence{
              journal {
                plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.sql-server"
                  sql-server {
                      # qualified type name of the SQL Server persistence journal actor
                      class = "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"

                      # dispatcher used to drive journal actor
                      plugin-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"

                      # connection string used for database access
                      connection-string = "Data Source=MyMachineName\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

                      # default SQL commands timeout
                      connection-timeout = 30s

                      # SQL server schema name to table corresponding with persistent journal
                      schema-name = dbo

                      # SQL server table corresponding with persistent journal
                      table-name = EventJournal

                      # should corresponding journal table be initialized automatically
                      auto-initialize = off

                      # timestamp provider used for generation of journal entries timestamps
                      timestamp-provider = "Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Journal.DefaultTimestampProvider, Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common"

                      # metadata table
                      metadata-table-name = Metadata
                  }
              }

              snapshot-store {
                  sql-server {

                      # qualified type name of the SQL Server persistence journal actor
                      class = "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotStore, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"

                      # dispatcher used to drive journal actor
                      plugin-dispatcher = ""akka.actor.default-dispatcher""

                      # connection string used for database access
                      connection-string = "Data Source=MyMachineName\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

                      # default SQL commands timeout
                      connection-timeout = 30s

                      # SQL server schema name to table corresponding with persistent journal
                      schema-name = dbo

                      # SQL server table corresponding with persistent journal
                      table-name = SnapshotStore

                      # should corresponding journal table be initialized automatically
                      auto-initialize = off
                  }
              }
          }
        }
        """)
config.WithFallback(ClusterSingletonManager.DefaultConfig())
```

**The following line results in the exception that I described:**

```
let system1 = System.create "cluster-system" (configWithPort 2551)
```

In conclusion, I am new to Akka.Net and am struggling to troubleshoot why this exception is occurring.

Comment: My guess is that \ in your connection string is breaking parser appart. Try to use \\ instead.

Comment: That fixed it! Can you post this as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like HOCON parser may have a problems with `\` and treats it as escaping character. Changing that to `\\` should solve the issue.